# Mutating native prototypes with Symbol.for

Tags: javascript

So, I was thinking about this problem, where you were adding something to native prototype (say, doing String.prototype.func = ...) for readability and convenience, and thus leaving a chance to get a disastrous bug in the future.
I've came up with an idea though, how you can possibly work around this issue. Using ES6 symbols you can just add any methods, getters and such to a native prototype with 100% guarantee that they will never be overwritten. My ìmplementation looks something like that:

```
const sym = {
   last: Symbol('last') 
};

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, sym.last, {
    get: function() {
        return this[this.lenght - 1]
    }
});

// usage
[1, 2, 3][sym.last] 
// 3. Less readable than [1, 2, 3].last,
// but better, than making an independent function
```

My question is: what possible pitfalls of such an approach can be there? For example, if I want to implement a whole library that way, will it somewhat significantly affect performance of my script?

Comment: This is actually the only real usecase for symbols, so i think whoever introduced this language feature made sure that browsers can optimize it well, so no it should not affect performance.

Comment: Javascript needs a [pipe operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator) (quote, `[...] and provides a practical alternative to extending built-in prototypes.`) :( I want to write `[1, 2, 3] |> myLib.last`. What libraries currently do is the same without pipe, e.g. [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#last), but imho chains of operations including dot notation aswell as being used as parameters have very bad readability, as the order is zig-zag through the code.

Comment: Performance-wise this shouldn't be an issue. You won't be able to invoke these methods dynamically by referring to the method name, e.g. do something like `let methodName = 'slice'; obj[methodName].call(obj, ...args)` (you can use `Symbol.for()`, but for that you have to know that the method you're trying to reach was defined as a symbol) . It's up to you to decide if that's a problem for you.

Comment: @MátéSafranka, I'm actually providing every Symbol through webpack.ProvidePlugin and using it everywhere in my project almost painlessly